# Dependency injection bug: unable to instantiate 'app'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I am trying to get a express/angular app online and am getting a confusing bug.  Console readout indicates the following:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'app' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

I understand that this is usually reserved for dependencies that are not included correctly, but what about when it is for the app itself?  I have the following declarations of 'app:'

server.js:

```
var app = express();
//other init code here
module.exports = app;
```

application.js:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
```

index.jade

```
doctype html
html(lang="en" ng-app="app")
  head
  title Bloom
  link(rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css")
  //- link(rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/foundation.min.css")
  link(rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/main.css")

  script(type="text/javascript", src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.js")
  script(type="text/javascript", src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js")
  script(type="text/javascript", src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/2.4.1/lodash.min.js")
  script(type="text/javascript", src= "/angular-ui-router.min.js")
  script(type="text/javascript", src= "/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js")
  script(type="text/javascript", src= "/controllers/home.js")
  script(type="text/javascript", src= "/routes.js")
  script(type="text/javascript", src= "/application.js")

  body
    div(ui-view)
```

What is going on here?  I am not sure how to solve this.

Comment: This is an angular error, so likely not related to express unless express is failing to serve the static files angular requires.

Comment: Did you take a look in `resources` tab in `chrome` to be sure all dependencies are effectively loaded? In your server did you server static files :`var path = require('path');`  `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`

Comment: Sorry for the poor formatting, but I also get these 404 errors when I load the server.  Could this have anything to do with it?

localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:3000/main.css 

localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:3000/routes.js 

localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:3000/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js 

localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:3000/controllers/home.js 

localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:3000/application.js 

localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:3000/angular-ui-router.min.js'

Comment: do they show 200 or 304 status code?

Answer (score 0):

### You need to serve your static files (scripts, css...)

#### Node Js Express : `how to` serve `static files`( css, js...) :

*Assuming you placed your static files in a `public` folder*

```
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```